# how to add errors in reactive forms which is for dynamic input fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive form and I have added dynamic text fields.

This is my Component:
 my html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="ProductKeyRequestForm" novalidate>
     <div formArrayName="PartNumberInfoList">
                            <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of formData(ProductKeyRequestForm); let i = index;let last=last" [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="col-md-1 icon">
                                    <div (click)="addProductReq()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add New Row" *ngIf="last"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle "></i> </div>
                                    <div (click)="RemoveproductReq(i,last)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete Row" *ngIf="!last"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle "></i> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="PartNumber" formControlName="PartNumber" class="form-control">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="number" min="0" pattern="\d+" required placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="Quantity" class="form-control">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" required formControlName="SKU" class="form-control">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

my ts file

```
 ngOnInit() {

            this.ProductKeyRequestForm = this._fb.group({

                PartNumberInfoList: this._fb.array([this.ProductReq()]),
            });

        }
        ProductReq() {

            let ProductReqInfo = this._fb.group({
                PartNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],
                Quantity: [''],
                SKU: [''],

            });
            return ProductReqInfo;
        }
        formDataDays(invoiceForm: any) {
            return invoiceForm.get('PartNumberInfoList').controls;
        }
```

After submitting the form I will potentially get row errors from the backend, and I have to show those in the UI: [image: u can find image preview]
How to achieve this?

Comment: Share your HTML?

Comment: i shared my html-Vikas

Comment: This link might help:https://www.puzzle.ch/de/blog/articles/2017/01/18/server-side-validations-with-angular-2